# XSL How to put a tag inside a tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt, hta

OK I have a code like this

```
<a href="ApplicationTesterResult_APPSRV.hta">

<xsl:value-of select='COMPONENT_NAME'/> 

</a>
```

I want to replace `APPSRV` with `<xsl:value-of select='COMPONENT_NAME'/>`

So far this doesn't work:

```
<a href="ApplicationTesterResult_ <xsl:value-of select='COMPONENT_NAME'/>  .hta">
```

Comment: You can't put a tag inside a tag. Did you try `href="ApplicationTesterResult_{COMPONENT_NAME}.hta"`? Or, you could define a variable with a concatenated value, and set the attribute using `<xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></xsl:attribute>`.

Comment: Well done for using the term "tag" correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put a tag inside a tag. You could use attribute value templates, using `{}`:

```
<a href="ApplicationTesterResult_{COMPONENT_NAME}.hta">
    <xsl:value-of select="COMPONENT_NAME"/>
</a>
```

Or, you could set the attribute specifically:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('ApplicationTesterResult_', 
            COMPONENT_NAME, '.hta')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="COMPONENT_NAME"/>
</a>
```